Отслеживается ли через rdp демонстрация экрана с домашего ноута?
Всем привет! Такой вопрос. Если подключаюсь через rdp на удаленнный рабочий комп, можно ли отследить что я включил демонстрацию экрана со своего домашнего ноута? Если что rdp не сворачивается

нет.
Если ты записываешь не в самом rdp, то ничего не будет видно.

спросите в службе безопасности своей организации, они точно знают.
